# nginx alias+location directive

Tags: nginx, location, alias

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name  pwta; 
    root html;

    location /test/{
        alias html/test/;
        autoindex on;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

This configuration works.  However, if `location /test/` is replaced e.g. `location /testpath/` it doesn't work (No input file specified). I assumed base on the explanation of alias directive that the "location" part is dropped and thus `/testpath/info.php` would result in `html/test/info.php`.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 12):

[nginx alias](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,3059,3060#msg-3060)

```
    server {
    listen      80;
    server_name  pwta;
    index index.html index.php;
    root html;

    location /testpath/ {
        alias html/test/;
    }
    location ~  ^/testpath/(.+\.php)$ { ### This location block was the solution
        alias html/test/;     
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$1;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
     location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: I don't fully understand why that works, but it does indeed solve the problem.  Could anyone add more explanation as to what is going on with that middle location block?

Comment: Adding `alias` will effectively overwrite the `$document_root` to whatever is the alias. Note that it will not affect `$fastcgi_script_name` or `$request_filename`. Using the new `$document_root` together with regex matching the file name, resolves to the script file.

Comment: Note the last location block is not doing anything when request is under `/testpath/`.

Comment: I've been struggling for 4 hours now ... until I found this answer ... phew!

Answer (score 9):

Both the `alias` and `root` directives are best used with absolute paths. You can use relative paths, but they are relative to the `prefix` config option used to compile nginx, and are generally not what you want.

You can see this by executing `nginx -V` and finding the value following `--prefix=`.

Prove this to yourself by looking at the log, you will find a "no such file" error.

Comment: Note that should be `-V` not `-v` (should be capital, lowercase just gives version number)