# Alias uses --prefix instead of server block's root

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set up a nginx server and alias my static files.

```
server {
    # Listen on localhost:8000;
    listen 8000;

    # Should be the root
    root /Users/rouvenherzog/Documents/projects/nd;

    # host matches localhost
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
            root /Users/rouvenherzog/Documents/projects/nd/n/n/static/img;
    }

    location ~ /([\w]+)/n/static/(.*) {
            alias n/n/static/$2;
    }

    location ~ /([\w]+)/nb/static/(.*) {
            alias nb/nb/static/$2;
    }
}
```

When request static files, it looks for them in the nginx --prefix folder ( which is /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.6.0_1 ), instead of the root folder.

For instance:

```
open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.6.0_1/n/n/static/neb/js/javascript.js" failed
(2: No such file or directory),
client: 127.0.0.1,
server: localhost,
request: "GET /pages/n/static/neb/js/javascript.js HTTP/1.1",
host: "localhost:8000",
referrer: "http://localhost:8000/pages/n/"
```

Any idea why ?

Thank you very much!

---

**As @akawhy suggested, using a rewrite instead of alias works and respects the root path.**

```
server {
    # Listen on localhost:8000;
    listen 8000;

    # Should be the root
    root /Users/rouvenherzog/Documents/projects/nd;

    # host matches localhost
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
            root /Users/rouvenherzog/Documents/projects/nd/n/n/static/img;
    }

    location ~ /([\w]+)/n/static/(.*) {
        rewrite ^([\w]+)/n/static/(.*)$ /n/n/static/$2 break;
    }

    location ~ /([\w]+)/nb/static/(.*) {
        rewrite ^([\w]+)/nb/static/(.*)$ /nb/nb/static/$2 break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your *alias* directive used a **relative** path. I think you should use a **absolute** path instead.

You may check this [nginx alias+location directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084137/nginx-aliaslocation-directive)

Comment: If I use an absolute path it ignores the root completely. I therefore need to copy the root into the alias. À la

    alias /Users/rouvenherzog/Documents/projects/nd/n/n/static/$2;

This solution doesn't make use if the root directive and a change in this variable means I need to update all my locations..

Comment: @RouvenHerzog Maybe you can try to use rewrite directive. like `
rewrite ^/([\w]+)/n/static/(.*)$ /n/n/static/$2 break;`. then the uri will serve in the root

Comment: True! That works. But I have to add another location /n/n/static/(.*) BEFORE the rewrite location. Otherwise I get an `rewrite or internal redirection cycle` error. That works and uses the $root, thank you @akawhy! Downside an empty location.

Comment: @RouvenHerzog you can add **break** in your rewrite directive to avoid  
rematch. visit [nginx doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) to see more rewrite info